# Help with Ubuntu 18.04 and GoPro Hero 6 Black

Tags: devices, camera

When I connect my camera to my PC, on the camera screen, a *USB Connected* message appears, but I can't find it on Nautilus like a USB stick.

If I put the microSD on the PC, I can access it from Nautilus as a USB stick.

When I run `lsusb` with the camera plugged in (USB), I see a line stating `BUS`, `DEVICE` and `ID` without description. If I unplugged it and run `lsusb`, that line does not appear, then I imagine it to be the camera.

When I run the `lsblk` command with the camera connected (USB), only my local disk is displayed (`/dev/sda` and its partitions). If I remove the camera and connect the microSD to the PC and run `lsblk`, I can see `/dev/sdb1`.

When I run `tail -f /var/log/syslog`, I see some camera outputs, such as:

- gopro, hero 6 black (no error msg).

Note: On Windows, I can access it connected by USB.

MicroSD formatted as exFat by Ubuntu disks program, the camera recognizes the card and works normal.

Anyone with more experience who can give me tips on where to go to get this access by USB?

Having to turn off the camera, remove the battery to remove the card every time I need to copy the files is discouraging me.

I'm using :

- gnome 3.28.4
- kernel 5.0.0-32-generic
- gphoto2 2.5.15
- libgphoto2 2.5.23
- exfat-fuse 1.2.8-1
- exfat-utils 1.2.8-1
- gmtp 1.3.10-1

P.S : The output of command

```
gphoto2 --list-cameras | grep -i gopro
```

displays `GoPro Hero 6 Black`